# $ne: Compare Date of entry with field in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I created a test collection for this and it looks like this:

```
{
    "createDate": ISODate("2021-01-04T15:00:00.000+00:00"),
    "arr": [
        {
            "date": ISODate("2021-01-04T15:00:00.000+00:00")
        }
    ]
},
{
    "createDate": ISODate("2021-01-04T16:00:00.000+00:00"),
    "arr": [
        {
            "date": ISODate("2021-01-04T15:00:00.000+00:00")
        }
    ]
}
```

The only difference is: The first entry has the same date, the second one has different dates.

Now I want to create a query to find all entries, where the two dates are different. I tried it with this:

```
db.getCollection('test').find(
    {
        "createDate": { $ne: "arr.0.date" }
    }
)
```

Unfortunately, this query delivers me both entries. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It requires to match in [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) expression, that compare fields from the same document, to access element from specific index use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html)

```
db.getCollection('test').find({
  $expr: {
    $ne: [
      "$createDate",
      { $arrayElemAt: ["$arr.date", 0] }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i1DEfYfRLA9)

Comment: Thank you, that works! But could you please explain, why I need the `$expr`? Is it only because of `$arrayElemAt`, what one cannot use in a query?

Comment: Tehre are 2 conditions, 1) when we match condition on external value `{ createdAt: "2020-12-12" }`,
2) to match reference field / internal field / both fields in document, `{ createdAt: "$arr.date" }` that requires $expr, otherwise match will identify this is external match not internal.
this is not only for $arratElemAt, it requires when put condition in internal documents fields check [playgorund](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8mfYcC9ih9k)